# How to access vm storage from webjob?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Because Azure has no native FTP capabilities, I created a small VM where clients can drop files.  I have a separate webjob that will process those files but I can't figure out how to get access to the files from the webjob.  I first created a blob thinking i could attach it to the VM but that doesn't seem to be possible.  How is this done?

Comment: Where are you storing those files?

Comment: Currently, I'm using IIS' FTP capabilities to drop the files into a folder on the VM's C drive.  I either need to find a way for the webjob to access the VM's C drive or I need a way for the VM to write to blob storage so that the webjob can access the files.  I realize that everything is technically blob storage on Azure but when under a VM, it's seen by the server as a normal hard disk.

Comment: You can't access the C drive of another VM directly. Maybe you should use Azure files which is SMB file shares? No need for FTP.

Comment: I had not considered that as I'm not really familiar with it but after a quick search, that seems like it would be an excellent option.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonnyBravoJr, what did you end up doing for this? I have a similar requirement -- client needs to upload files via SFTP, but I need to process in a WebJob or other worker role. Did you end up using blob storage or something like that?

Comment: Well, I did get it to work but I honestly don't remember how.  We became so frustrated with problems we were having with WebJobs, we moved everything over to AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the C drive of another VM directly. Maybe you should use Azure files which is SMB file shares? No need for FTP. You can access that share from anywhere and it should be quite easy to use.

For small temporary the cost should be near zero.